# Align tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I,

I want this two tikzpicture to be side by side. Without changing my code, is that possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bchart}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\def\stackalignment{r}
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}




\def\stackalignment{r}
\newcommand\pielabelon[3][0pt]{%
\abovebaseline[#3]{#2%
    \makebox[-\dimexpr8pt+#1]{\smash{%
            \stackunder{}{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr#3+2.5ex}}}}}
}
\newcommand\pielabelunder[3][0pt]{%
\belowbaseline[#3]{#2%
    \makebox[-\dimexpr8pt+#1]{\smash{%
            \stackon{\rule{0pt}{1.3ex}}{\rule{1pt}      {\dimexpr#3+2.5ex}}}}}
}

\newcommand{\slice}[4]{
\pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
\let\midangle\pgfmathresult

% slice
\draw[thick,fill=black!10] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

% outer label
\node[label=\midangle:#4] at (\midangle:1) {};

% inner label
\pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
\let\temp\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
\let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
\node at (\midangle:\innerpos) {#3};
  }

  \newcounter{a}
  \newcounter{b}

  \begin{document}


  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[In-only]{\label{fig:in}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \newcounter{i}
  \newcounter{j}
  \foreach \p/\t in {
45/Absolute Return Bonds, 
45/Emerging Market Debt,
7/Equity (7\%),
3/Property (3\%)}
   {
\setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
\addtocounter{b}{\p}
\slice{\thea/100*360}
{\theb/100*360}
{\ifnum\p>10\relax\p\%\fi}{\t}
   }

  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
   \quad
      \subfloat[In-only]{\label{fig:in}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

   \newcounter{e}
  \newcounter{h}
   \foreach \p/\t in {
45/Absolute Return Bonds, 
45/Emerging Market Debt,
7/Equity (7\%),
3/Property (3\%)}
     {
\setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
\addtocounter{b}{\p}
\slice{\thea/100*360}
{\theb/100*360}
{\ifnum\p>10\relax\p\%\fi}{\t}
    }

   \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

I tried to do it using subfloat but is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you mean by *without changing your code*; you will have to change *something*. The problem is that the figures take too much horizontal space to be placed side by side (provided you do not want to extend the text width). The aesthetic problem is the automatic placement of the two long labels. I suggest to replace `Absolute Return Bonds` by

```
\makebox[1.3cm][r]{Absolute Return Bonds}
```

and `Emerging Market Debt` by

```
\makebox[1.3cm][l]{Emerging Market Debt}
```

which results in the following picture. You can modify the position of the labels by playing around with the length of `1.3cm`.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help. And is it possible to have the legend Absolute Resturn Bonds on two lines? I tried to use `\makebox[1.3cm][r]{Absolute Return\\ Bonds}` but didn't work